# Outlook web client html email images and ImageProxy.mvc

Tags: html, image, email, proxy, outlook

I'm having a problem with images in html emails in Outlook web client.

When a you put a image like this:

```
<img src="http://www.nortpalet.com/newsletter/green_btn.png"</a>
```

Outlook change the src for:

```
https://dub112.mail.live.com/Handlers/ImageProxy.mvc?bicild=&canary=Gff8%2btl0q5SE4gsUVuSNwElf3c8f0rsyViXwF0k6Sy8%3d0&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.nortpalet.com%2fnewsletter%2fgreen_btn.png
```

and the browser can't find any image in this url.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Accidentally we discovered that proxifying on Microsoft's mail services applies only for HTTP images, not for HTTPS ones. So if you have HTTPS endpoint just use it prior HTTP one for images.

Why do that for HTTP? I don't know but maybe to get rid of secure notifications on having HTTP content on HTTPS page.

Comment: Also, there another thing to keep in mind.
Outlook ImageProxy blocks urls with IP (e.g. `http://123.123.123.123/image.png`) and you should use links like `http://example.com/image.png`
p.s. We faced with this problem on development server and spent additional time to investigate it

Answer (score 0):

You can check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx Outlook doesn't support some css attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Changing http in https made the image appear correctly.