# Email with image via external path C#

Tags: c#, html, email

Here is a situation. 
I am sending an email that has image as html body

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="click me" />
```

After receiving email image src is changed to

```
<img src="https://bay179.mail.live.com/Handlers/ImageProxy.mvc?bicild=&amp;canary=ei12UmVJE9u9hgMk5TdV12Y1X%2b9Vc365IL%2bmULwd%2bfk%3d0&amp;url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com%2fimages%2fsrpr%2flogo11w.pngf" alt="click me">
```

Hence does not render image. Following is the code used to send email

```
SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
            sc.Port = 587;
            sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someemail@hotmail.com", "password");
            sc.EnableSsl = true;
            MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
            m.From = new MailAddress("someemail@hotmail.com");
            m.Subject = "test subject";
            m.IsBodyHtml = true;
            m.Body = "<img src=\"http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png\" alt=\"click me\" /><img src=\"https://campaign-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/newsletter/2015/19Apr_wk17/EN/images/logo.jpg\" />";
            m.To.Add(new MailAddress("someemail@hotmail.com"));
            sc.Send(m);
```

First image url gets changed and second image's url remains same. So whats the science?
I don't want to embed image.

Comment: You are going to need to post your code. Without knowing how you are setting the image source we can't do much.

Comment: This is Microsoft/Live/Outlook.com proxying the image as a security precaution so is about that facility, not C# - IIRC HTTPS prevents this

Comment: _"Hence does not render image"_ - not until the user clicks "Display images".

Comment: Since the embedded URL is not correct, Clicking "Display images" wont work

Comment: When you say the embedded URL is not correct, were you expecting it to be just the google.com URL? Or do you mean e.g. the trailing 'f' on the URI-encoded google.com URL within the ImageProxy URL? Or something else?

Comment: [This old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438766/outlook-web-client-html-email-images-and-imageproxy-mvc) says it might be because you're using HTTP not HTTPS for the URL, and [this question on microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/why-is-outlookcom-imageproxy-breaking-images-for/7b5c1e36-f153-41dc-b367-67e986bf0ef8) suggests it might be because some domains are black-listed for images. Is there a good reason you're trying to put a Google logo in your email, from an URL you don't control? Does it work for images sourced elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Once you send the e-mail you have yielded control to the receiving system. Most MTAs are going to do some kind of reformatting either due to anti-virus, phishing, etc. scans. Many will rework the img source to use their own proxies. You have no way to stop them. You just get to work with them.

Comment: I have done a POC and found that while sending email on smtp.live.com with two different image urls. One gets changed and one remains the same, so i think there must be a mechanism thought which one has changed.
Following are the two URLS and 2nd one gets changed.
[link](
https://campaign-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/newsletter/2015/19Apr_wk17/EN/images/logo.jpg)
[link](https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png)

Comment: It's not (usually) the sending MTA it's the receiving one. When you send to Google, Hotmail, etc. you will get different results.